# Is it possible to use the bulkloader for incremental exports?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

Is there a way to use the bulk loader incrementally?

I'd like to export all entities of type X overnight, then a day later export any new entities that may have been created.

(I was hopeful, because the bulkloader creates progress and results sql files, that this might be possible. But I see no mention of it in documentation -- less hopeful.)

Comment: I should note that I have `created` and (where needed) `updated` timestamps on all of my entities of type X. So it's certainly possible for *me* to write code to do this. But I'm wondering if I can convince the bulkloader to issue queries that will pull out just the new entities I want.